# Javascript 0 == '0'. Explain this example

Tags: javascript

I found these examples in another thread but I don't get it.

```
0 == '0'            // true
```

0 to the left I converted to false(the only number that does that). The right is a non empty string which converts to true.
So how can
false == true --> true

What have I missed?

Comment: Before someone will close it: http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: Use '===' instead of '=='. See this for more clarity : http://java67.blogspot.in/2013/07/difference-between-equality-strict-vs-operator-in-JavaScript-Interview-Question.html and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript .

Comment: I know this stuff. But why is this happening in this case is the question.

Comment: @Kay – please read question carefully, iw was about how to JS parser works not what is the difference between `==` and `===`

Comment: Why you downvote the man question as it was pointing to another duplicated question with 2000 votes up?

Comment: 0 doesn't get casted to false, instead, the string `"0"` gets casted to the number 0.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski it's not a parsing question - all the parser will see is "operand ; == operator ; operand".  It's down to the _interpreter_ to decide how to cast the operands as necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an official answer to your question (the quoted parts, link at the bottom) and analysis:

### Equality (==)

> The equality operator converts the operands if they are not of the same type, then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the string operand is converted to a number if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.
>   Syntax
>
> x == y
>
> Examples
>
> 3   == 3   // true
>
> "3" == 3   // true
>
> 3   == '3' // true

This means, as I read it, that the first 3 (integer) is converted to string to satisfy the comparison, so it becomes `'3' == '3'`, which is true, same as in your case with zeroes.

**NOTE**: I assume that the converion may vary in different JS engines, although they have to be unified under ECMAScript specifiction - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3 (**quoted @Derek朕會功夫**). This assumption is made on a subjective and imperative opinion that not all browsers and JavaScript engines out there are ECMAScript compliant.

### Identity / strict equality (===)

> The identity operator returns true if the operands are strictly equal (see above) with no type conversion.

The **Identity / strict equality (===)** found on the same resource at the end of the answer will skip the automatic type conversion (as written above) and will perform type checking as well, to ensure that we have exact match, i.e. the expression above will fail on something like:

`typeof(int) == typeof(string)`

This is common operator in most languages with weak typing:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing

I would say that one should be certain what a function/method will return, if such function/method is about to return numbers (integers/floating point numbers) it should stick to that to the very end, otherwise opposite practices may cut your head off by many reasons and one lays in this question as well.

The above is valid for other languages with weak typing, too, like PHP for example.

Read more of this, refer second head (Equality operators):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Here is where I got confused. 0 doesn't get casted to false, instead, the string "0" gets casted to the number 0.

Comment: @user874774 - Read the specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3 Fourth point.

Comment: Rolice, typing casting won't vary since it is clearly defined in the ECMAScript specification. (Although some browsers might not follow it...I'm talking about you IE!)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, yep I doubt too, but I have to mention it. There are a lot of browsers, some official other not, cannot be sure for each one. I have quoted your argument as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `==` JavaScript will try very hard to convert the two things you are trying to compare to the same type. In this case `0` is converted to `'0'` to do the comparison, which then results in `true`.

You can use `===`, which will not do any type coercion and is best practice, to get the desired result.

### Equality operator

> The equality operator converts the operands if they are not of the same type, then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the string operand is converted to a number if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

JavaScirpt Table Equality: http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/